# How to make Visual Studio Code Angular friendly

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ide, editor, development-environment

I'm trying to setup my local development environment for Angular project.

I'm familiar  with Visual Studio Code IDE as a seasoned React developer, but I don't know which is preferred editor for Angular. I tried to install *Angular Essentials (Version 11)* VS Code extension by John Papa, but editing the template doesn't seem Angular aware.

For instance, I would like to enable following aids

- Property and event binding auto completion
- Curly braces auto completion
- Structural directives auto  completion
- Template aware refactoring
- Adding new modules and components via editor
- Seamless code navigation on components and templates

Is this feasible with VS Code, or should I use different IDE for Angular development?

Comment: yes you can do all this in vscode just try to install some of the extensions i have listed to you in the answer

Comment: also enable strict templates helps a lot with Angular Language Service extention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Answere enlists some of the important `Visual Studio Code extensions` that can help you for `Angular` developement.

- Path Intellisense
- Angular Snippets
- Angular2-Switcher
- Angular Files
- REST Client
- JSON to TS
- Angular Language Service
- Angular2-Inline
- TSLint
- Material Icon Theme

Comment: If you on angular 11 then TS lint is depreciated and you should use ESLint

Comment: Yes that's true